# Looking for a SEO plugin for Drupal

Tags: 7

For my internship I could use some help with the optimization for search engines.

Are there any plugins that will help me increase the SEO performance of the website im trying to optimize? So far I only found a checklist but thats not what im looking for. Wordpress has a Yoast plugin that checks every move I make to optimize it for search engines. Does Drupal have a similar plugin?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question is vague at the moment, and will be pretty biased. Decompose what SEO actually consists of, and search for those modules. That will also help you understand what are you dealing with, instead of installing one "magical" module. See [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect), [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap), [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) and [Page Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title) for a start.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the following was a bit like Yoast . SEO Compliance Checker - https://www.drupal.org/project/seo_checker

Once downloaded install and enable.

SEO Checklist

Basic SEO Modules

Keyword Rules

Then go to configuration .

Once those modules have been enabled you’ll then have a nice set of Sliders to use in the ‘Thresholds for the SEO Rules’ box.
Set up your sliders depending on what the recommended levels are at the time.
From here you’ll then need to visit the Article that you want to optimise .

> Click on PREVIEW

The Keywords are taken from 'tags' .